# Where Do Temporary Tables Get stored in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, temp-tables

Where do temporary tables get stored in a database? I want to drop a temporary table if it already exists.
I can do this for securable tables by querying at information schema but I don't know where temporary tables are stored.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Temporary tables are stored in [tempdb Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190768.aspx). There are various ways to check if a temp table exists outlined here: [Check If Temporary Table Exists](http://sqlservercodebook.blogspot.com/2008/03/check-if-temporary-table-exists.html).

Answer (score 8):

Temporary tables gets stored in tempdb database which is present in SystemDatabase
or
SystemDatabase -> tempdb -> Temporary Tables

Answer (score 4):

TempDb Will In in SystemDatabase.Temp tables are stored here.

Answer (score 3):

Store at this table

```
SELECT *
FROM   tempdb.sys.tables
```

Delete query:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @sql = ISNULL(@sql + ';', '') + 'drop table ' + QUOTENAME(NAME)
FROM   tempdb..sysobjects
WHERE  NAME LIKE '#%'

EXEC (@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find all your temp tables (both local and global) which are stored and active using SSMS.

[image]