# Performance difference between Views and Temporary tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, view, temp-tables

Is there any major difference in the performance of the Views and Temporary tables.  I have situation like to migrate data from one database to the other. I have to extract the source data from views to the tables in the destination db.

As there are no unique field in it I tried extracting the data from views into Temporary table and the process it to push the data into destination table. I don't find any major performance changes with respect to time.

Answer (score 7):

The main difference between temporary tables and views is that temporary tables are just the tables in tempdb, but views are just stored queries for existing data in existing tables. So, there is no need to populate the view, because the data is already here. But temporary table needs to be populated first, and population is the main preformance-concerned issue.

Comment: I agree with your point that it takes time to populate the Temporary table, but my concern is like when there is data in the temp table after population .. which would give maximum peroformance .. like the temporary tables are in the cache memory it can be faster compared to views?

Comment: No, they are both stored on disk in same manner. I think you just need examine the query execution plans in both cases.

Comment: is it like the views are also on the cache memory like the Temporary tables?

Comment: Temporary tables are stored in tempdb database, not in memory. For example, you can re ad bout it here http://aartemiou.blogspot.com/2009/04/where-are-temporary-tables-stored-in.html and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012662/where-does-temporary-tables-gets-stored-in-sql-server .